# is it bad to have a high precision, recall, and fbeta on a 1:5 imbalanced dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, imbalanced-data

i have a research using random forest to differentiate if data is bot or human generated. the machine learning model achieved an extremely high performance accuracy, here is the result:

```
Confusion matrix: 
 [[420   8]
 [ 40  20]]
Precision:  0.9130434782608695
Recall:  0.9813084112149533
F-BETA:  0.9668508287292817
```

my question is would this result be valid for research?